# multinomial/conditional logit with grouped data in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multinomial, mlogit, vgam

I'm looking for a way to fit a conditional logit on grouped data in R. I have multinomial choice counts with response- and individual-specific variables. Unfortunately, the expanded dataset would be too huge to work with it. Thus I can't use most of the packages I know, `mlogit` for example.
I discovered `vglm` from the `VGAM` package but it doesn't work if one explanatory variable is missing for a response category.

Has someone tried something similar in R ?

Thanks!

Comment: I've not used it myself so I'm not sure it will meet your specific requirements, but  there is a package called `mclogit` that might do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've already tried `mclogit`. It only fits conditional models (with (mixed) or without random effect). So only response specific variables can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use clogit in the survival package by setting the strata to your group id.